# chrome not reading download attribute instead playing it

Tags: download, href

the download attribute works in IE correctly but in edge one file downloads but the other start playing instead of downloading.chrome just play both files

Comment: Can you please include your code attempts and also include an actual question ?

Comment: theres no problem in code but actually the file for download plays because the html page and file are in the computer not uploaded yet